# Dependency Injection via constructor create only one instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I would like to ask how to create a proper Dependency Injection via constructor to create a list of unique object. Now i have this kind of situation:
1) I adding an object to the list of my objects, however each subsequent overwrite all previous one (i.e. it is not unique).
2) I refer to the factory class statically. However in this case i do not use a dependency injection in constructor of this interface.

Is there any other solution possible.

Thanks for all answers.

Example it is not 100% same code (because my list is also initialized by constructor):

```
 class GetUserFirstOption
        {
            IUser _user;
            GetUserFirstOption(IUser user)
            {
                _user = user;
            }

            public void UsersInCompany()
            {
                //Here is connection to the database where i upload 500 records to UsersFromDataBase

                List<User> UsersInCompany = new List<User>();
                foreach (var userDB in UsersFromDataBase)
                {
                    _user.Name = userDB.Name;
                    _user.SecondName = userDB.SecondName;
                    //...

                    UsersInCompany.Add(_user);
                    //Here i have 500 users but all same

                }
            }
        }



      class GetUserSecondOption
        {
            public void UsersInCompany()
            {
                List<User> UsersInCompany = new List<User>();
                foreach (var userDB in UsersFromDataBase)
                {
                    _user = Factory.CreateNewUser();
                    _user.Name = userDB.Name;
                    _user.SecondName = userDB.SecondName;
                    //...

                    UsersInCompany.Add(_user);
                    //I have 500 unique records but i do not need to it dependency injection

                }
            }
        }



class Factory
{
   public static IGetUserSecondOption CreateUserInCompany()
   {
      return new GetUserSecondOption(UserFactory.CreateNewUser());
   }
}

class UserFactory
{
  public static IUser CreateNewUser()
  {
      return new User();
  }
}


class Program
{
  public static Main(string []args)
  {            
    IGetUserSecondOption Get = Factory.Factory.CreateUserInCompany();
    Get.UserInCompany();
   }        
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample-code that illustrates what you want to achieve and where specifically you have problems?

Comment: This question is very unclear, you need to clarify or provide some code. From what i understand you need to take a look on the Singleton Pattern

Comment: I added part of code.

Comment: @Nkosi you blocked me faster than i reacted...

Comment: Why do you even use DI in this occasion? just create a new user inside the foreach loop. You can also use  UsersInCompany.Add(_user.DeepClone());
but that's a very dirty solution.

Comment: So you want to create a new `User` on each iteration? Of course you can´t inject a single user to your class and use that again and again, as `User` is a class and thus a reference-type. I agree crankedrelic: why not create the user diretly in the loop? If you really want to inject it, you may use a factory that creates the `User`-instances, someting like `UsersInCompany.Add(theFactory.CreateUser(name, secondName, ...))`. Then you can inject the **factory**, not the **user**.

Comment: Hey HimBromBeere thank you for your clear response ;).

Comment: @Adriaan Hey, I updated my post can you return me the permission?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know that i can create the user directly in loop but i wanted to write it using SOLID principles or I did it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting a **user** to your loop, create a factory that creates users. Then you may inject the **factory** instead:

```
class GetUserSecondOption
{
    public GetUserSecondOption(UserFactory factory) { this.Factory = factory; }
    public void UsersInCompany()
    {
        List<User> UsersInCompany = new List<User>();
        foreach (var userDB in UsersFromDataBase)
        {
            var user = this.Factory.CreateNewUser();
            user.Name = userDB.Name;
            user.SecondName = userDB.SecondName;
            //...

            UsersInCompany.Add(user);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HimBromeBeere Hey as you can see in my edited code i can not inject the factory because I have constrcutor of my class in Factory class. ..return new GetUserSecondOption(CreateNewUser());

Comment: @Drax well, I don´t know if or if not you need to inject a facory or if you can use a static one as well. In this case you don´t need to inject **anything**. Just remove the `_user`-field, as there is no **single** user that belongs to your class. Having a `_user`-member thus is pretty pointless.

Comment: I did that :). Can you tell me one more thing, is it good to create more than one class in Factory. I mean that in factory will be only creater of constructor: GetUserSecondOption but in other classes like UserFactory will be creation of individual instances.

Comment: @Drax Of course your factory can create different classes. However be aware of the single-responsibility-pronciple. Factories that create `User`s, `Animal`s and `Building`s at the same time tend to break that.

Comment: look at edited code and Factory and UserFactory is in one file and in one namespace (or it should be in one file ~~class)? What do you thing about this kind of concept?

Comment: @Drax Seems like over-complicating your problem, That would apply to an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), where you first create a concrete factory that itself creates concrete instances of a specific entitiy. Of course you **can** do it, but I don´t know if you really **need** it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a factory here seem like a code smell and in my opinion over engineering.

Reference [Abstract Factories are a Code Smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/)

Referring to the factory statically creates tight coupling, that can have unwanted results when trying to unit test in isolation. The class is also not being genuine about what it needs to perform its designed function.

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

The creation of a model for the purpose of persistence where there are no knock on or adverse effect of simply creating the instance and populating its members really does not need the additional complexity of a factory abstraction.

```
public void UsersInCompany() {
    List<User> UsersInCompany = new List<User>();
    foreach (var userDB in UsersFromDataBase) {
        User user = new User() {
            Name = userDB.Name,
            SecondName = userDB.SecondName,
            //...
        };
        UsersInCompany.Add(user);    
    }
}
```

There are also services like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) that could be used to simplify the process

```
public class UsersService {
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public UsersService(IMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper
    }

    public List<User> UsersInCompany() {            
        List<User> UsersInCompany = new List<User>();
        foreach (var userDB in UsersFromDataBase) {
            User user = mapper.Map<User>(userDb);
            UsersInCompany.Add(user);
        }
        return UsersInCompany;
    }
}
```

The `IUser` also appears to be an abstraction of a data model, which might indicate a misunderstanding of the principles, but as the question is a simplified example, I may stand corrected if the situation is way more complex than first indicated.

Comment: "Referring to the factory statically creates tight coupling" True, but your first code also statically relies on `User`, which has therefor the exact same problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I disagree. `User` in that snippet is a data model and not a service. It would not fall under tight coupling.

Comment: Well, as OP wants to inject it, I assume it **does** fall under this category. It even implements an interface, which makes me assume we have some additional logic appart from pure data. But maybe it´s just me assuming, This seems to go far beyond what OP provided.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I think the OP is an XY Problem. But I believe that is because of a misunderstanding of the design principle, which I also indicated in my answer.

Comment: Btw.: doesn´t creating dependencies (even if DTOs) within the code violate what you mentioned by the explicit dependency principle? I suppose that´s exactly what OP's question is about.

Comment: @HimBromBeere not it does not. That is also one of the things that get misunderstood a lot. Understanding what is a dependency, and the misinterpretation of the whole "new is glue" statement